# Excel Macro to replace accented chars with close equivalent characters

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel Macro that seems to work to replace some diacritic chars in a spreadsheet with the closest English equivalents.

I need to add more to the list of diacritics to search for.

I don't need an "authoritative/full" list (and the replacement chars), ideally just those commonly used in major European usage (umlauts, accents etc.)

I was hoping a programmer here would have a list of diacritics (or better, the VBA code, like mine, using them) that they commonly use in a programming language to give a better solution than in the code below.

```
Sub Replace_Diacritics()
    With Cells
        .Replace What:="á", Replacement:="a", MatchCase:=False
        .Replace What:="é", Replacement:="e", MatchCase:=False
        .Replace What:="í", Replacement:="i", MatchCase:=False
        .Replace What:="ó", Replacement:="o", MatchCase:=False
        .Replace What:="ú", Replacement:="u", MatchCase:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly? Here is a few, all frequently used in hungarian: á é í ó ö ő ú ü ű. I suggest using the ascii codes instead, as I have seen VBE cock up some (especially ű and ő).

Comment: Furthermore, the question is much too broad. There are too many languages and special characters within (I am guessing) continental Europe to be considered. @s2016 you should at least name the languages / countries to include. Yet, the following might be a good starting point: http://www.roblocher.com/technotes/specialchars.html#allspecialchars

Comment: I feel it's a relevent question.  I was hoping a programmer here would have a list of diacritics (or better, the VBA code, like mine, using them) that they commonly use in a programming language to fix this. Isn't this a common coding question/issue?  I'm not a linguistics expert so I stated my question as I did on purpose.

Comment: No problem, and don't get offended. But it is not a common problem. Usually you don't want to replace those characters, they are there for a reason, not just decoration. For example, "szár" means "stem", while "szar" means "shit". Not the same. :)

Comment: @vacip -- I googled and found this a somewhat common coding question with plenty of attempted solutions on the web (including my code above, which partially but not fully addresses the problem).  Was just hoping for a broader solution.

Comment: @Scott Holtzman - I'd like to respectfully disagree with your "off topic" / "not at all a programming question" comment and your downvote (which may pre-empt any "constructive" discussion here.)  Why? 1) There are similar discussions on other VBA Coding forums on this same question:  see  http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/266749-replacing-accented-characters-non-accented-equivalents.html and http://www.excelbanter.com/showthread.php?t=209704 2) difficult to separate out coding Qs and character set questions - they are clearly interrelated. (1 of 2 -- cont'd)....

Comment: @Scott Holtzman —2 of 2 — 3) I'm looking for VBA Code and I quoted VBA code as a starting point.  It's a coding solution I'm looking for.  Topic had a VBA / Excel-VBA tag.   I have no doubt that **programmers** out there have VBA code to do what I have asked for the European languages' diacritic chars that I specified in my OP.

Comment: @s2016 - point taken. DV removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range of char codes 192..609 contains 221 char that are representable in ASCII (i. e. can be converted from diacritic chars):

> À Á Â Ã Ä Å Æ Ç È É Ê Ë Ì Í Î Ï Ð Ñ Ò Ó Ô Õ Ö Ø Ù Ú Û Ü Ý à á â ã ä å æ ç è é ê ë ì í î ï ñ ò ó ô õ ö ø ù ú û ü ý ÿ Ā ā Ă ă Ą ą Ć ć Ĉ ĉ Ċ ċ Č č Ď ď Đ đ Ē ē Ĕ ĕ Ė ė Ę ę Ě ě Ĝ ĝ Ğ ğ Ġ ġ Ģ ģ Ĥ ĥ Ħ ħ Ĩ ĩ Ī ī Ĭ ĭ Į į İ ı Ĵ ĵ Ķ ķ Ĺ ĺ Ļ ļ Ľ ľ Ł ł Ń ń Ņ ņ Ň ň Ō ō Ŏ ŏ Ő ő Œ œ Ŕ ŕ Ŗ ŗ Ř ř Ś ś Ŝ ŝ Ş ş Š š Ţ ţ Ť ť Ŧ ŧ Ũ ũ Ū ū Ŭ ŭ Ů ů Ű ű Ų ų Ŵ ŵ Ŷ ŷ Ÿ Ź ź Ż ż Ž ž ƀ Ɖ Ƒ ƒ Ɨ ƚ Ɵ Ơ ơ ƫ Ʈ Ư ư ƶ Ǎ ǎ Ǐ ǐ Ǒ ǒ Ǔ ǔ Ǖ ǖ Ǘ ǘ Ǚ ǚ Ǜ ǜ Ǟ ǟ Ǥ ǥ Ǧ ǧ Ǩ ǩ Ǫ ǫ Ǭ ǭ ǰ ɡ

You can try the below simplest function, but it's drawback is that all Unicode chars, which are not representable in ASCII will be replaced with `?`:

```
Function Replace_Diacritics(strText)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2
        .Mode = 3
        .Open
        .Charset = "ascii"
        .WriteText strText
        .Position = 0
        Replace_Diacritics = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function
```

Other one more complex function replaces only the chars, which are representable in ASCII, the rest chars are unchanged:

```
Function Replace_Diacritics(strText)

    Static objDict As Object
    Dim i, strRange, strCured, strChar, arrRes

    If objDict Is Nothing Then
        Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        strRange = ""
        For i = 192 To 609
            strRange = strRange & ChrW(i)
        Next
        With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
            .Type = 2
            .Mode = 3
            .Open
            .Charset = "ascii"
            .WriteText strRange
            .Position = 0
            strCured = .ReadText
            .Close
        End With
        For i = 192 To 609
            strChar = Mid(strCured, i - 191, 1)
            If strChar <> "?" Then objDict(ChrW(i)) = strChar
        Next
    End If

    arrRes = Array()
    ReDim arrRes(Len(strText))
    For i = 1 To Len(strText)
        strChar = Mid(strText, i, 1)
        If objDict.Exists(strChar) Then
            arrRes(i) = objDict(strChar)
        Else
            arrRes(i) = strChar
        End If
    Next
    Replace_Diacritics = Join(arrRes, "")

End Function
```

Comment: Omegastripes, thanks for your excellent solution.